# prefixing github page with www return 404

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a Github page set up and I noticed when I try to open it with 'www' added, I am getting 404ed, I don't understand what may be the cause for it.

Its the case for any github page, I am using a public page as an example here:

https://square.github.io/ works flawlessly whereas https://www.square.github.io/ seems to return a security warning followed by a 404

I am curious to understand what might be causing this problem.

PS- I don't have very good understanding of Publishing websites or HTML, I am expecting it may as well be a very silly doubt from my end